# Radiobutton group not working in DataTable Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I generate 20rows dynamically, while using datatable jquery for pagination , sorting and searching.

My Issue : I have a radiobutton on each row with same name (Radio button group). If i select one radiobutton on page1 and navigate to second page And also i select one radiobutton on second page and back to page1. The selection is still available. But as per the radiobutton group only one button should be enable on those two pages... right?

Comment: You need to just disable the other(radiobutton) when one is enabled

Comment: did you even try before saying something useless like that .??? the other page of resultat seems to not be available on the DOM

Comment: I've just come across exactly the same issue...